# fetching user details on successful login

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I don't have hands on the API. I am using the provided URL to check the validity of a user based on its email. If the email and password match the data already present in API, I need to display them. I tried the part that has been commented now. Can someone help me?

```
$('#checkbutton').on('click',function(){ 
                var self = this;
                // var data={
                // email: $('#emailer').val(),
                // txtpaswrd: $('#paswrder').val()
                // }

                // var resultElement = $('#resultDiv');

                var email = $('#emailer').val();
                var txtpaswrd = $('#paswrder').val();



                      $.ajax({
                      type: "GET",
                      data: data,
                      processData:false,
                      contentType:false,
                      dataType:"json",
                      url: 'http://13.229.164.32/users/user_check.json?email=' + email, 
                      success: function(nData){

                        alert(nData.password);
                        alert(nData.email);
                        if(email == nData.email && txtpaswrd == nData.password ){



                               //window.location = 'http://13.229.164.32/users.json';

                      }else{ 
                          alert('Password Error');
                     }

                }




                      });

                });
```

Comment: Well what's actually happening currently? Since we don't know your API, it's impossible for us to say what's wrong at this stage. Also, sending login credentials over GET is a pretty unsafe thing to do.

Comment: Instead of one particular user (the one who is logging in), the page redirects to a JSON page of the complete API data.

Comment: It's impossible for us to answer this without being familiar with the API/web service you're calling. You'll need to speak to the developers behind that. There's no general problem here. Perhaps it's expecting POST and you're sending GET (I can't imagine an authentication web service that accepts GET.)

Comment: Thanks will try changing the method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#checkbutton').on('click', function() {
  var email = $('#emailer').val();
  var password = $('#paswrder').val();
  var $resultElement = $('#resultDiv');
  var URL = 'http://13.229.164.32/users/user_check.json?email=' + email;
  $.getJSON(URL, response => {
    var result = reponse.password == password ? "Password is a match." : "Passwords don't match.";
    $resultElement.html(result)
  });
});
```